# django change label in a included .html form template - e.g. from "Add" to "Save"

Tags: django

I have written a form template to be used in different templates with the include tag.

```
 {% include "crm/contact_form.html" %}
```

This form includes a submit button. Now I want to change the label of the button according to the circumstances the form is used.

For example if the form is included in a add template the label should be "Add" and in a detail template the label should be "Save".

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will either need to put the label into a context variable where it can be used by the `contact_form.html` template or switch from `{% include %}` to an [inclusion tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) which will let you pass arguments like this:

```
{% load contact_form %}
...
{% contact_form mylabel %}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I have chosen the inclusion tag, which works fine for this use-case.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Van's method, you can set the variable in the enclosing template via `with`:

```
{% with "Add" as mylabel %}
  {% include "crm/contact_form.html" %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [Django 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/#reusable-form-templates), you can combine the include and with tags

```
{% include "form_snippet.html" with form=comment_form %}
```